# Select box persists with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I am having a JSP page which includes another JSP which has all the common customized popup boxes. On my main JSP page I have a button that says "Cancel". when I press this the Javascript is invoking a `div` which is present in the JSP file which I have included.

The invoked pop up has a `div` and in it there is a dropdown box. The user can select the reason from the dropdown box. Now if the user closes the pop-up box and clicks the Cancel button again, the dropdown box persists the value that was selected earlier.

I want to make the value to go to default. If I refresh the page the value is removed. I tried to refresh the page but then it gives an alert to confirm the submission, which doesn't look good in the terms of user experience.
I am using Struts 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: could you post the code u have tried??

Comment: $('#selectCancellationReason option[value="0"]');
 //var x=document.getElementById("selectCancellationReason");
 //x.setAttribute(headerkey,"-1");
 //$("#selectCancellationReason").val("0");
 //document.getElementById("selectCancellationReason").options[0].value = "0";
 //document.getElementById("selectCancellationReason").selectedIndex="0";

Comment: did u try autocomplete="false" for the select element?

Comment: just tried it but not working

Comment: Bhadra can we do something like refreshing that particular div without refreshing the complete page

Comment: i think refreshing is not possible.try resetting the content of the div using .html() in jquery or innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem. Posting here for others.
My html code

```
<select name="cancel.cancelReasonCode" 
        id="selectCancellationReason" 
        data-theme="c" 
        data-mini="true" 
        data-native-menu="false" 
        tabindex="-1">
    <option value="0">Select Cancellation Reason</option>
    <option value="3">Created by mistake</option>
    <option value="2">Incorrect Id</option>
    <option value="1">Data not available</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code

```
var myselect = $("select#selectCancellationReason");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

I am using jquery and jquery mobile in my application.